# Django email through microsoft mail host SMTPSenderRefused

Tags: django, django-email

This is my send_email method

```
class EmailTemplate(models.Model):
    type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=_UserProfile.NOTIFICATIONS_TYPES.get_choices(), unique=True, db_index=True)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField()


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.get_type_display()


    def send_email(self, context, to_email, use_thread=True):
        template = Template(self.body)
        c = Context(context) 
        html = template.render(c)

        sender = 'Jack <%s>' % settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL

        email_message = EmailMessage(self.subject, html, sender, to_email)
        email_message.content_subtype = 'html'

        if use_thread:
            t = threading.Thread(target=email_message.send, kwargs={'fail_silently': False})
            t.setDaemon(True)
            t.start()
        else:
            email_message.send()
```

These are my email settings

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'Jack <info@jack.com>'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.live.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'info@jack.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
```

When I try to send an email I get the following error

```
[Tue Jul 23 22:33:28 2013] [error] Exception in thread Thread-1:
[Tue Jul 23 22:33:28 2013] [error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Jul 23 22:33:28 2013] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
[Tue Jul 23 22:33:28 2013] [error]     self.run()
[Tue Jul 23 22:33:28 2013] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 505, in run
[Tue Jul 23 22:33:28 2013] [error]     self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
[Tue Jul 23 22:33:28 2013] [error]   File "/home/jack/sites/universal_tutors/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 248, in send
[Tue Jul 23 22:33:28 2013] [error]     return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
[Tue Jul 23 22:33:28 2013] [error]   File "/home/jack/sites/universal_tutors/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 92, in send_messages
[Tue Jul 23 22:33:28 2013] [error]     sent = self._send(message)
[Tue Jul 23 22:33:28 2013] [error]   File "/home/jack/sites/universal_tutors/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 110, in _send
[Tue Jul 23 22:33:28 2013] [error]     email_message.message().as_string())
[Tue Jul 23 22:33:28 2013] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 720, in sendmail
[Tue Jul 23 22:33:28 2013] [error]     raise SMTPSenderRefused(code, resp, from_addr)
[Tue Jul 23 22:33:28 2013] [error] SMTPSenderRefused: (501, '5.5.4 Invalid Email address', 'Jack <Jack>')
```

When I use gmail smptp settings its working but with the microsoft mail I am getting the errors. Don't know what is the mistake I am making.

Comment: Can you show us your real settings (with the password stripped out obviously)? I don't see how you ended up with `Wizoku <Wizoku>` in your traceback with the settings you posted.

Comment: Its just a typo mail is sending from info@jack.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
sender = 'Jack <%s>' % settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
```

Since you've got:

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'Jack <info@jack.com>'
```

You end up with `sender` being:

```
Jack <Jack <info@jack.com>>
```

which isn't a valid email address.